# How to query in list inside list inside list.... MongoDB aggregate query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, any

I have a collection of documents "**EvaluationGroups**" in which each evaluation group object has a list of **Evaluations**.
Each Evaluation object has a list of **Detail** objects.
And each Detail contains a list of **Label** objects. Label is an object with a property named "LabelId" and a property named "Value".
(Details define a combination of labels and show some other data, and each combination of labels represents a different kind of evaluation type).

Example doc:

[image]

What I would like to do, is to filter all Evaluations in the lists inside EvaluationGroups, that have Details with any Label with the same LabelId and LabelValue (strings) of a Label given.
So, to sum up, I want to **filter evaluations by label**.

How can I achieve this with a mongodb query, using aggregate and match stages?

I tried this:

```
{ "$match" : 
{ 
    "$expr" : { 
            $anyElementTrue: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: [ "$Evaluations.Details.Labels.LabelId", "5fe34b13f0031e1078e08b5c" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$Evaluations.Details.Labels.Value", "CREDIT" ] }
                        ]
            }
    } }}
```

But I get 0 results, knowing that I do have evaluations that have that label given (with that Id and Value)..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: show us some sample docs

Comment: True, show some documents. Have you tried using the $unwind operator ? You shoud get way more documents but then it's easier to manipulate. The doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: @Gibbs, I added a sample image of the document!

Comment: @Pilybius I edited to add a sample image of the document

Comment: Do you have a scenario of multi match inside Labels array?

Comment: Why do you especially need `anyElementTrue` ?

Comment: @Gibbs I don't specially need it, I was just testing it.. I still can't find the way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TeGRAvgSFhh)

You used `Id` whereas your field is `LabelId`. Hence it didn't work.

You can simplify your query as mentioned below

> have Details with any Label with the same LabelId and LabelValue (strings) of a Label given

```
{
    "$match": {
      $and: [
        {
          "Evaluations.Details.Labels.LabelId": 1
        },
        {
          "Evaluations.Details.Labels.Value": "b"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If there are multiple match, it will return only the first match. It works similar to `$elemMatch` If you need to retrieve all matched Labels with the given Id and value, you need to make your query complex.

If it is the complete requirment, you can use [this variant](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sVDsAg2BIu9)

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "Evaluations.Details.Labels.LabelId": 1
    },
    {
      "Evaluations.Details.Labels.Value": "b"
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Yes, I changed LabelId to Id here to make it less confusing, but I was using it well.
This still returns 0 results.
I need the evaluations that have this label in any combination of labels in its details..
(I need to use $match, because there's some lookup and other things happening before)